# NHibernate - Retrieve specific columns and count using criteria query

Tags: c#, nhibernate, joined-subclass

This is my mapping file:

```
class name="CRMStradCommon.Entities.OportunidadEntity,CRMStradCommon" table="oportunidad">

    <id name="Id" column="id" type="int">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Titulo" column="titulo" type="string" not-null="true" />
    <many-to-one name="Estado" column="estado" class="CRMStradCommon.Entities.EstadoOportunidadEntity,CRMStradCommon"  />
    <many-to-one name="Dueno" column="dueno" class="CRMStradCommon.Entities.ContactoEntity,CRMStradCommon"  />
    <property name="FechaCierreEstimado" column="fecha_cierre_estimado" type="DateTime" not-null="false"/>
    <property name="FechaVencimiento" column="fecha_vencimiento" type="DateTime" not-null="false"/>
</class>
```

This is the other with joined-subclass

```
class name="CRMStradCommon.Entities.ContactoEntity,CRMStradCommon" table="contacto"  dynamic-update="true">
    <id name="Id" column="id" type="int">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Nombre" column="nombre" type="string" not-null="true" />
    <property name="Email1" column="email1" type="string" />
    <property name="Email2" column="email2" type="string" />
    <property name="Web1" column="web1" type="string" />
    <property name="Web2" column="web2" type="string" />
    <bag name="DuenoOportunidadList" lazy="true" inverse="true">
        <key column="dueno"/>
        <one-to-many class="CRMStradCommon.Entities.OportunidadEntity,CRMStradCommon"/>
    </bag>
    <joined-subclass name="CRMStradCommon.Entities.EmpresaEntity,CRMStradCommon" table="empresa" lazy="false">
        <key column="id" />
        <many-to-one name="Categoria" column="categoria" class="CRMStradCommon.Entities.CategoriaEmpresaEntity,CRMStradCommon"  />
        <many-to-one name="Calificacion" column="calificacion" class="CRMStradCommon.Entities.CalificacionEmpresaEntity,CRMStradCommon"  />
    </joined-subclass>
    <joined-subclass  name="CRMStradCommon.Entities.PersonaEntity,CRMStradCommon" table="persona" lazy="false">
        <key column="id" />
        <property name="Saludo" column="saludo" type="string" />
        <property name="Apellido" column="apellido" type="string" />
        <property name="SegundoNombre" column="segundo_nombre" type="string" />
    </joined-subclass>
</class>
```

How can I make this query with criteria?

```
SELECT     
    contacto.id, contacto.nombre, persona.apellido, COUNT(*) AS Cant
FROM         
    contacto 
INNER JOIN
    oportunidad ON contacto.id = oportunidad.dueno 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    persona ON contacto.id = persona.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    empresa ON contacto.id = empresa.id
GROUP BY 
    contacto.id, contacto.nombre, persona.apellido
ORDER BY 
    contacto.nombre, persona.apellido
```

Thanks a lot!

Thanks a lot! It solved a part of my problem. I did this:

```
ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(ContactoEntity));
criteria.SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                    .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Id"),"Id")
                    .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Nombre"),"Nombre")
                    .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Apellido"), "Apellido")
                    .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("TipoContacto"), "TipoContacto")
                    .Add(Projections.RowCount(),"CantOportunidadesDueno"));
criteria.CreateCriteria("DuenoOportunidadList");
criteria.AddOrder(Order.Asc("Nombre")).AddOrder(Order.Asc("Apellido"));
criteria.SetResultTransformer(
                    new NHibernate.Transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(ContactoEntity)));

IList<ContactoEntity> ContLst = (criteria.List<ContactoEntity>());
```

I used Transformer in order to make a collection of `Contacto` entities, but the problem is with property `Apellido`. I have it in subclass Persona and the collection is made only with parent class and not with children classes.

do you know if it is possible to solve that? or the only solution I have is to go throw each collection item without using transformer and creating a new collection of Contacto entities creating each new object?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use projections.  Something like this:

```
session.createCriteria(ContactoEntity.class)
  .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.groupProperty("id")
    .add(Projections.groupProperty("nombre")
    .add(Projections.groupProperty("apellido")
    .add(Projections.rowCount()));
```

UPDATE - I just noticed that you're using NHibernate, and I'm a Java user so the code snippet I gave may need to be tweaked for your use.  Hope it helps.